# How to print float as string in Golang without scientific notation

Tags: go

Suppose I have an array with 2 items whose type is string / float.
How should I print them together without scientific notation for float item.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    values := []interface{}{"mydata", 1234567890.123}
    for _, v := range values{
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", v)
    }
}
```

The output will be

> mydata
>
> 1.234567890123e+09

What I want is

> mydata
>
> 1234567890.123

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) explains it: The `%v` verb is the default format, which for floating numbers means / reverts to `%g` which is

> %e for large exponents, %f otherwise. Precision is discussed below.

If you always want "decimal point but no exponent, e.g. 123.456", use `%f` explicitly.

But you can only use that for floating numbers, so you have to check the type of the value you print. For that you may use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) or [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Example:

```
switch v.(type) {
case float64, float32:
    fmt.Printf("%f\n", v)
default:
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", v)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A9eklQ7Hqau)):

```
mydata
1234567890.123000
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `%f` to print a float.
Given your slice of interfaces, you first need to check the type of the element. You can do so as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    values := []interface{}{"mydata", 1234567890.123}
    for _, v := range values {
        // Check if the type conversion to float64 succeeds.
        if f, ok := v.(float64); ok {
            fmt.Printf("%f\n", f)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
mydata
1234567890.123000
```

The full list of flags for floats from [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) is:

```
%b  decimalless scientific notation with exponent a power of two,
    in the manner of strconv.FormatFloat with the 'b' format,
    e.g. -123456p-78
%e  scientific notation, e.g. -1.234456e+78
%E  scientific notation, e.g. -1.234456E+78
%f  decimal point but no exponent, e.g. 123.456
%F  synonym for %f
%g  %e for large exponents, %f otherwise. Precision is discussed below.
%G  %E for large exponents, %F otherwise
```